# error: expected ')' before numeric constant 6 | #define TFT_RST 8 6

Tags: arduino-ide

Installed arduino 2.04 on new pc.win 10 pro.
added all the libraries i need for my sketch.
Specifically, Adafruit HX8357 v 1.1.15
Teensy 4 connected to this display
https://www.adafruit.com/?q=hxd8357&sort=BestMatch

started writing code.

```
#include "Adafruit_HX8357.h"
#include <Bounce.h>

#define TFT_CS 10
#define TFT_DC 9
#define TFT_RST 8 6
Adafruit_HX8357 tft = Adafruit_HX8357 (TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);
```

did a verify/compile on this.
got this error:

```
C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202331-9772-phra3o.j87e8\sketch_apr1a\sketch_apr1a.ino:7:39: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token
    7 | Adafruit_HX8357 tft = Adafruit_HX8357 (TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);
      |                                       ^
C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202331-9772-phra3o.j87e8\sketch_apr1a\sketch_apr1a.ino:6:19: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
    6 | #define TFT_RST 8 6
      |                   ^
C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202331-9772-phra3o.j87e8\sketch_apr1a\sketch_apr1a.ino:7:56: note: in expansion of macro 'TFT_RST'
    7 | Adafruit_HX8357 tft = Adafruit_HX8357 (TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);
      |                                                        ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202331-9772-phra3o.j87e8\sketch_apr1a\sketch_apr1a.ino:7:39: note: to match this '('
    7 | Adafruit_HX8357 tft = Adafruit_HX8357 (TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);
      |                                       ^

exit status 1

Compilation error: expected primary-expression before '(' token
```

Perhaps the syntax has changed?
The same code compiled fine on previous machine with Arduino 1.89

Comment: Thank you. Change your comment to an answer so I can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0):

Macros are simple text replacements, so `Adafruit_HX8357 (TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST)` in the original post will expand to `Adafruit_HX8357 (10, 9, 8 6)` which is obviously invalid

> Replacing `#define TFT_RS 8 6` with `#define TFT_RST (8, 6)` gives this error:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202331-9772-phra3o.j87e8\sketch_apr1a\sketch_apr1a.ino:6:18: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
>     6 | #define TFT_RST (8, 6)
>       |                  ^
> C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202331-9772-phra3o.j87e8\sketch_apr1a\sketch_apr1a.ino:7:56: note: in expansion of macro 'TFT_RST'
>     7 | Adafruit_HX8357 tft = Adafruit_HX8357 (TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);
>       |                                                        ^~~~~~~
> ```

As the warning already says clearly, the macro will now be replaced to `Adafruit_HX8357 (10, 9, (8, 6))` which is equivalent to `Adafruit_HX8357 (10, 9, 8)` because `left operand of comma operator has no effect`. However that's only a *warning* and compilation will complete successfully because the code still matches the [second constructor](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_HX8357_Library/blob/master/Adafruit_HX8357.h#L127) even though it's not what you expected. The error in this case is different because they're all **linker errors** (`undefined reference to ...`):

> ```
> c:/users/stefan/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/teensy/tools/teensy-compile/11.3.1/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\FAF4EC7B25DF20D04735FE9464C6799E/..\..\cores\teensy_avr_teensy41_usb_serialhid,speed_600,opt_o2std,keys_en-us_300b8394b6e6311256a6e28440722b2d\core.a(main.cpp.o): in function `main':
> C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\teensy\hardware\avr\1.58.0\cores\teensy4/main.cpp:51: undefined reference to `setup'
> c:/users/stefan/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/teensy/tools/teensy-compile/11.3.1/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\teensy\hardware\avr\1.58.0\cores\teensy4/main.cpp:53: undefined reference to `loop'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

The same linker issue occurred when you change `#define TFT_RS 8 6` with `#define TFT_RST 8, 6`. You need to fix the linking issue. See [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/995714)